# Tkinter Beginner Having problems with my error code about master and etc

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

My code worked fine without OOP,

Now I am trying to implement it in OOP, but somehow cause some errors.

Could someone help please?

BTW the error is:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2059, in _setup
>       self.tk = master.tk
>   AttributeError: class MainInterface has no attribute 'tk'"

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont

class MainInterface:
    def __init__(self, master):
            self.master = master
            # Main interface created
            master.title("Dijkstra's Algorithm Solution Demonstrator")
            # Title for the main interface
            self.TNR24 = tkFont.Font(family="Times New Roman", size=24, weight="bold")
            self.TNR28 = tkFont.Font(family="Times New Roman", size=28, weight="bold")
            # Two font types that can be used later
            master.overrideredirect(True)
            master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(master.winfo_screenwidth(), master.winfo_screenheight()))
            # Formats the interface so that it would be in full screen
            self.MainTitle = Label(MainInterface, text="Dijkstra's Algorithm Solution Demonstrator", bg="white", font=self.TNR28)
            self.InterfaceMenu = Menu(MainInterface)
            self.MainInterface.config(menu=self.InterfaceMenu)

            self.submenu1 = Menu(self.InterfaceMenu)
            self.InterfaceMenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.submenu1)

            self.submenu2 = Menu(self.InterfaceMenu)
            self.InterfaceMenu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=self.submenu2)
            self.submenu2.add_command(label="details")

            self.MainInterfaceButton1 = Button(MainInterface, text="Input New Question", font=self.TNR24, command=create_window)
            self.MainInterfaceButton2 = Button(MainInterface, text="Load Up Existing Question", font=self.TNR24)
            self.MainInterfaceButton3 = Button(MainInterface, text="Identify Incorrectly Applied Algorithms", font=self.TNR24)
            # Three main buttons created for that interface
            self.ExitButton = Button(MainInterface, text="Exit", command=self.exit_window)
            # Exit button created
            self.MainTitle.pack()
            # Packs the main title onto the interface
            self.MainInterfaceButton1.place(x=340, y=200, width=600, height=100)
            self.MainInterfaceButton2.place(x=340, y=350, width=600, height=100)
            self.MainInterfaceButton3.place(x=340, y=500, width=600, height=100)
            self.ExitButton.place(x=1240, y=670, width=40, height=30)
            # Places the buttons at desirable places
            self.MainInterface.configure(background="white")
            # Makes the background colour white

        def exit_window(self):
            self.quit()
            # Function for existing the interface


def main():
    root=Tk()
    Lookatthis=MainInterface(root)
    root.mainloop


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Is `root.mainloop` only referenced and not actually called in your real code, or is this a copy-paste error?

Comment: What's the [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which still has the problem?

Comment: show full error message.

Comment: Where is `self.MainInterface` even defined?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have problem because you have to use `master` instead of `MainInterface` in `Label`, `Button`, etc.

```
... = Label(master, ... )
... = Button(master, ... )
... = Menu(master, ... )
```

-

`MainInterface` is not Tkinter widget and it can't be parent (master) for other widgets.

Comment: Also `self.MainInterface` should be `master`, `root.mainloop` needs to be `root.mainloop()`, `self.config` needs to be `master.config`, `create_window` needs defining, as does `quit` if you want it to exit without errors. Other than that, it works (c: